# Style table of contents - titles below numbers InDesign CS6

Tags: adobe-indesign, table-of-contents

I am trying to recreate the table of contents style in the image below. I have made a table of contents with paragraph styles and am wanting to make the titles drop below the numbers like in the example. Is it just hitting the return key?

[image]

Here is my Table of contents.

[image]

Comment: Erm… as far as I can tell, the titles _aren’t_ below the numbers in the picture – the numbers are below the titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the numbers come *after* the titles, so I assume that's what you want.

If you aren't going to update your TOC, you can just manually edit it like any other text.

If you need it to be able to update automatically, you need to enter *Layout > Table of Contents* and make sure that the *Page Number* comes *After Entry*. Furthermore set *Between Entry and Number* to `^n` to insert a *Forced Line Break* between the entry and the number. (You can instead insert `^p` to insert a *Paragraph Return*, but it doesn't really do much good as you can't specify a *Paragraph Style* for the number anyway - only a *Character Style*.)

[image]

Comment: `^p` might be useful if, for some reason, your general TOC style is (left-)justified, in which case newline would make the ‘last’ line justified rather than ragged. But to be honest, if you’re using justification in a TOC, you probably have bigger problems than this…